Expo splash screen: getting rid of <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splashscreen_logo</item>
I'm migrating an old react-native to RN 0.76 and expo.
When doing a prebuild --clean it generates a styles.xml with this line present that we really want to get rid of
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splashscreen_logo</item>

We want to use the in-app splash that 'expo-splash-screen' provides, just not the ugly android launcher splash.
I have looked through ExpoConfig.d.ts and tried all combinations of configs but can't seem to get rid of it. Any pointers?

